# How to correctly perform all-VS-all row-by-row comparisons between series in two pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes, `df1` and `df2`. Both contain time series data.

**df1**

```
Event   Number  Timestamp_A
A       1       7:00
A       2       8:00
A       3       9:00
```

**df2**

```
Event   Number  Timestamp_B
B       1       9:01
B       2       8:01
B       3       7:01
```

**Basically, I want to determine the Event B which is closest to Event A, and assign this correctly.**

Therefore, I need to substract (1) every Timestamp_B in `df2` from ever Timestamp_A in df1, row by row. This results in a series of values, of which I want to take the minumum and put it to a new column in `df1`.

```
Event   Number  Timestamp_A Closest_Timestamp_B
A       1       7:00        7:01
A       2       8:00        8:01
A       3       9:00        9:01
```

I am not familiar with row-by-row operations in pandas.
When I am doing:

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    s = df1.Timestamp_A.values - df2["Timestamp_B"][:]
    Closest_Timestamp_B = s.min()
```

The result I get is a **ValueError:**

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes(3,) (4,)
```

**How to correctly perform row-by-row comparisons between two pandas dataframes?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better way to do this but here is one way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Event':['A','A','A'],'Number':[1,2,3],
                   'Timestamp_A':['7:00','8:00','9:00']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Event':['B','B','B'],'Number':[1,2,3],
                   'Timestamp_B':['7:01','8:01','9:01']})
df1['Closest_timestamp_B'] = np.zeros(len(df1.index))
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    df1['Closest_timestamp_B'].iloc[index] = df2.Timestamp_B.loc[np.argmin(np.abs(pd.to_datetime(df2.Timestamp_B) -pd.to_datetime(row.Timestamp_A)))]

df1 
Event   Number  Timestamp_A Closest_timestamp_B
0   A   1   7:00    7:01
1   A   2   8:00    8:01
2   A   3   9:00    9:01
```

Comment: works out well. Do you know a way to only include values for "Closest_timestamp_B" that date BEFORE the time in Timestamp_A, i.e. only discarding argmins that point to the future and only consider argmins that point to the past?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use the underlying numpy data structure to create a matrix of `Timestamp_A` by `Timestamp_B`.  Since you need to compare every event in A to every event in B, this is an O(N^2) calculation, well suited for a matrix.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['A',1,'7:00'],
    ['A',2,'8:00'],
    ['A',3,'9:00']], columns=['Event', 'Number', 'Timestamp_A'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['B',1,'9:01'],
    ['B',2,'8:01'],
    ['B',3,'7:01']], columns=['Event', 'Number', 'Timestamp_B'])

df1.Timestamp_A = pd.to_datetime(df1.Timestamp_A)
df2.Timestamp_B = pd.to_datetime(df2.Timestamp_B)

# create a matrix with the index of df1 as the row index, and the index
# of df2 as the column index
M = df1.Timestamp_A.values.reshape((len(df1),1)) - df2.Timestamp_B.values

# use argmin to find the index of the lowest value (after abs())
index_of_B = np.abs(M).argmin(axis=0)

df1['Closest_timestamp_B'] = df2.Timestamp_B[index_of_B]

df1
# returns:
  Event  Number         Timestamp_A  Closest_timestamp_B
0     A       1 2017-07-05 07:00:00  2017-07-05 09:01:00
1     A       2 2017-07-05 08:00:00  2017-07-05 08:01:00
2     A       3 2017-07-05 09:00:00  2017-07-05 07:01:00
```

If you want to return to the original formatting for the timestamps, you can use:

```
df1.Timestamp_A = df1.Timestamp_A.dt.strftime('%H:%M').str.replace(r'^0','')
df1.Closest_timestamp_B = df1.Closest_timestamp_B.dt.strftime('%H:%M').str.replace(r'^0','')

df1
# returns:
  Event  Number Timestamp_A Closest_timestamp_B
0     A       1        7:00                9:01
1     A       2        8:00                8:01
2     A       3        9:00                7:01
```

Comment: the nice thing with this solution is that I can easily exclude timestamp_Bs that point to the future of timestamp_A and vice versa by converting the matrix to a df and then doing matrix_df[matrix_df < 0] = None

Answer (score 1):

What about using [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) to get the closest events?

Make sure your data types are correct:

```
df1.Timestamp_A = df1.Timestamp_A.apply(pd.to_datetime)
df2.Timestamp_B = df2.Timestamp_B.apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Sort by the times:

```
df1.sort_values('Timestamp_A', inplace=True)
df2.sort_values('Timestamp_B', inplace=True)
```

Now you can merge the two dataframes on the closest time:

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, 
                left_on='Timestamp_B', 
                right_on='Timestamp_A', 
                suffixes=('_df2', '_df1'))
#clean up the datetime formats
df3[['Timestamp_A', 'Timestamp_B']] = df3[['Timestamp_A', 'Timestamp_B']] \
                                          .applymap(pd.datetime.time)
#put df1 columns on the right      
df3 = df3.iloc[:,::-1]

print(df3)
  Timestamp_A  Number_df1 Event_df1 Timestamp_B  Number_df2 Event_df2
0    07:00:00           1         A    07:01:00           3         B
1    08:00:00           2         A    08:01:00           2         B
2    09:00:00           3         A    09:01:00           1         B
```

Answer (score 0):

Use apply to compare Timestamp_A on each row with all Timestamp_B and get the index of the row with min diff, then extract Timestamp_B using the index.

```
df1['Closest_Timestamp_B'] = (
    df1.apply(lambda x: abs(pd.to_datetime(x.Timestamp_A).value - 
                            df2.Timestamp_B.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).value))
                            .idxmin(),axis=1)
       .apply(lambda x: df2.Timestamp_B.loc[x])       
)

df1
Out[271]: 
  Event  Number Timestamp_A Closest_Timestamp_B
0     A       1        7:00                7:01
1     A       2        8:00                8:01
2     A       3        9:00                9:01
```